# aws keep returning 502 bad gateway error using python flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

hi I've been trying for over a month on this..

so, I'm trying to test facebook oauth so have an [exact copy of flask oauth login sample code](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-oauth-example) which I put in my ec2 instance bought a domain and registered it on route 53, made an application load balancer and assigned my ec2 in it.

the port... I'm using flask default(5000) and security group setting has inbound port 5000(and others I've tried so far - made it for testing anyways) opened and `all traffic` on outbound. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKwfR.png)

health check is working perfectly fine. I can see from flask log it's working and returning 200.

but when I type in the domain name it's returning 502 bad gateway and I have no clue what's going on... typing in ip address of the ec2 instance works.. on ec2 instance side  where I've turned my app on returns code 400 bad request syntax [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e9dk.png) - i have no idea why words are cracked tried changing encoding formats and all failed.

so... I've checked security ports, have checked route53 if I assigned my instance on A-type record set correctly, ec2 instance itself seems to work fine, health check from target groups goes all fine, and I'm out of ideas on where i've done wrong. please help me on this....

stuck on one thing for a long time sure is stressful.. :(

EDIT:
curl -vvv {domain_name} returns:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: www.*.xyz/
*   Trying 1****...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.*.xyz (*) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.*.xyz
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: awselb/2.0
< Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2018 10:43:58 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 138
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host www.*.xyz left intact
```

EDIT2:
the reason for my `bad gateway error` was due to my target group was using https protocol. BUT I need this done with https... since oauth(facebook) only works under https....

Comment: can you do `curl -vvv <DNS name>` and post the results?

Comment: on terminal? forgot to mention... I use windows, will try and run it on ubuntu virtualmachine. just a moment...

Comment: done. added it on my question.

Comment: `typing in ip address of the ec2 instance works` are you sure about this? when I try to hit the IP in your logs, I get 502 error.

Comment: yes. the ip address of the instance is not that.

Comment: it's 13.125.143.173:5000. hmmm dont know where that ip is from...

Comment: that's the ELB IP, I guess the problem is with your ELB listener config, can you post your ELB settings?

Comment: I managed to re-create your problem, I guess you have selected HTTPS in your target group, can you create a new target group with HTTP and attach it to the load balancer. https://i.imgur.com/KlIyy7k.png

Comment: yes I have put https for my target group. but https is a MUST for me since oauth for facebook/google etc. only works under https. I will try http for now and check though.

Comment: just switched to http and it works... thank you for pointing it out.... so.... I guess my problem is on how to get this to work under HTTPS.... :(

Comment: since you already using HTTPS certificate on ELB, you don't need https on the instance, ELB does an SSL offloading, it should work fine. accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: I added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111282/how-can-i-fix-502-error-in-a-flask-application-that-i-uploaded-in-aws/63351418#63351418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 502 Bad Gateway error is an HTTP status code that means that ELB received an invalid response from the EC2 Instance.

I guess you have selected HTTPS in your target group, create a new target group with HTTP and attach it to the load balancer.

Comment: You are right. I had 2 Rest services running in EC2 in port 80. ELB is responsible for accepting HTTPS requests and then it forwards it to target groups (to EC2) in a plain HTTP.