# How can i fix 502 error in a flask application that i uploaded in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, flask

I'm having problems with uploading my flask app in an AWS server with elastic beanstalk. after I upload my code a 502 bad gateway error appears in the environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What port is your app running at?

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8080)

Comment: Default potr is 8000 or 5000. Have you adjusted your eb to use non default port?

Comment: I didn't configure the eb but I changed the port to 8000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
    print("Serving on port 8000...")
    httpd.serve_forever()

Comment: and it's the same 502 error

Comment: Check 5000. Sorry. Don't remember which one is that right now. Later I can double check.

Comment: On platforms like Heroku and AWS the server connected to the internet listens on port 80 and then it forwards traffic to an internal port that is usually configured with an environment variable. I don't know for sure if this will help, but why not try `port=$PORT` and see if letting AWS set the port for you works.

Comment: @DanSafee Yes, you can also change the EB settings to use the non-default port, using `PORT` env variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents after grappling with this for a few hours and using Flask/Eb for over a year.

Even the AWS tutorial did not work for me-- I kept getting this 502 error.

The reason why I ran into this error, whereas I had not before, was that I selected **Python 3.7** when creating the environment. This selection causes Eb to use nginx as the default proxy server. (To see this, go to your environment, select Configuration, and then Software)

The simple fix for me was to create a new environment and use **Python 3.6**, which worked like a charm.

Hopefully, someone finds a real solution because it would be nice to use Python 3.7, but this might even be an AWS bug considering I changed nothing about my code to get it to work (just the setup change from Python 3.7 to 3.6).

Comment: I already fixed this problem by uploading it directly from the elastic beanstalk CLI, but thank you for explaining why it had an error so now I can use the web version.

Comment: Sure, no problem